# getting json byte array in list

Tags: asp.net, web-services, arrays

I got null value for byte array in json web service when deserializing.but it returns byte array when invoked from browser.
C# Code:

```
var url = re.DownloadString("XXXX/ListService.svc/lstFooddtl/1/21");

 var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FooddtlResult>(url);
```

In a i got null for food_photo...when i deserialize...
**c# Class:**

```
public class photo
    {
        public byte[] food_photo { get; set; }

    }
public class Food
{
    public int food_id { get; set; }
    public string food_name { get; set; }
    public photo[] food_photo { get; set; }
    public string unitcost { get; set; }
}
public class FooddtlResult
{
    public Food[] Result { get; set; }
}
{"Result":[{"food_id":"61","food_name":"Idli","food_photo":[255,216,255,224,0,....217],"unitcost":null}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model does not match the JSON. For correct deserialization change your `Food` class to

```
public class Food
{
    public int food_id { get; set; }
    public string food_name { get; set; }
    public byte[] food_photo { get; set; }
    public string unitcost { get; set; }
}
```

and remove the `photo` class.

Otherwise, if you want to keep the model structure, then correct JSON should be:

```
{"Result":[{"food_id":"61","food_name":"Idli","food_photo":[{"food_photo":[255,216,255,224,0,....217]},{"food_photo":[255,...]},...],"unitcost":null}]}
```

Comment: thanks for ur rply!after changing food class again i got null in my food_photo list..

Comment: i have no rights change the json structure...i have only option to change my model structure..